# How to initialize an int array member of a structure?

Tags: arrays, structure

```
struct node {int n; int k; int arr[n]};
```

The size of the array n is not known before compilation. It is taken from the user during the execution.

Comment: This sounds like a homework assignment.

Answer (score 0):

you can take reference from this code,I am not sure whether it will work or not but you can take reference from this.

```
my_struct_t *myStruct;
size_t noOfElements;
size_t completeSize;
int index;    

/* ...code which sets the number of elements at runtime... */

completeSize = sizeof(my_struct_t) * noOfElements;

myStruct = malloc(completeSize);
memset(myStruct, 0, completeSize);

/* ...and then access it as if it were an array...*/

myStruct[index].someInt = 10; // index < noOfElements
```

Answer (score 0):

The memory cannot be allocated in the structure itself, but you can define a pointer to the array in your structure and then later you can allocate the memory using malloc or new() with the size of 'n'.

Here is the way you can define your structure.

```
struct node {int n; int k; int *arr};
```

To allocate memory you can do it using the object of the structure as follows,

1) using malloc:

```
fun() {
    node obj;
    obj.arr = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int)*obj.n);
}
```

2) using new()

```
fun() {
    node obj;
    obj.arr = new int(obj.n);
}
```